# sql union! extra results

Tags: sql, sql-server

struggling to apply the correct where clause each statement works alone but when combined in a union clause they seem to miss the last and statement

```
  SELECT TOP (1000) [1]
      ,[2]
      ,[3]
      ,[10]
      ,[11]
  FROM [dbo].[runner]WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([10],1,1)) = 1 
       AND datediff(month, [10], getdate()) >= 5 AND [2] NOT IN ('alsager')
       AND [2] NOT IN ('alsager') AND [11] = 0
union
 SELECT TOP (1000) [1]
      ,[2]
      ,[3]
      ,[10]
      ,[11]
  FROM [dbo].[runner] WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([10],1,1)) = 0 
       AND datediff(month, [3], getdate()) >= 5 AND [2] NOT IN ('alsager')
       AND [2] NOT IN ('alsager') AND [11] = 0
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the databases you are using.  (2) `SELECT TOP` is typically used with `ORDER BY` .  (3) `UNION ALL` is much preferred over `UNION`, unless you want to incur overhead for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want 1000 rows where a columns starts with `0` and another 1000 when a column starts with `1`.  That suggests window functions:

```
SELECT . . .   -- whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT([10], 1) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[runner] r
      WHERE [10] LIKE '[10]%' AND
            DATEDIFF(MONTH, [10], GETDATE()) >= 5 AND
            [2] NOT IN ('alsager') AND
            [11] = 0
     ) r
WHERE seqnum <= 1000;
```

Comment: sorry i didn't make it clear,, what makes the 2 select statements different is i want to do a datedif on a different column if column [10] has a date in it or not (i.e is numeric)